# extended_image_library-3.5.2/lib/src/network/network_image_web.dart:143:7: Error: 'ImageDecoderCallback' isn't a type

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/extended_image_library-3.5.2/lib/src/network/network_image_web.dart:143:7: Error: 'ImageDecoderCallback' isn't a type.
      ImageDecoderCallback decode,
```

I've tried already
`flutter clean`

`flutter pub get`